# Show "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"? error again and again how to fix permanent

Tags: php, mysql

When I open XAMPP and click start MySQL button and it gives me an error.

I have follow this steps to fix the problem:

1. Rename folder mysql/data to mysql/data_old
2. Make a copy of mysql/backup folder and name it as mysql/data
3. Copy all your database folders from mysql/data_old into mysql/data (except mysql, performance_schema, and phpmyadmin folders)
4. Copy mysql/data_old/ibdata1 file into mysql/data folder
5. Start MySQL from XAMPP control panel

I have follow this steps but after few days same error repeated. and these solution worked after follow 4 to 5 time. Still facing the problem.

Can you please mention any other possible problem ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally, there should be a mysql log.  What is logged in this mysql log?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is actually not recommended, unless for study purposes, so try installing mysql installer; https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Comment: "_XAMPP is actually not recommended, unless for study purposes_" I'm curious why that would be, do you have any links to support this or is this personal preference?

Comment: It is under apache blog itself https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html#:~:text=XAMPP%20is%20not%20meant%20for,environment%2C%20it%20could%20be%20fatal.

Quoted: "XAMPP is not meant for production use but only for development environments. XAMPP is configured to be open as possible to allow the developer anything he/she wants. For development environments, this is great but in a production environment, it could be fatal."